# How to correctly add javascript libraries to my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I want to include waypoints.js and counterup.js in my rails app, but I can't seem to figure out where to put them and how to require them.
At the moment I have both .js files in vendor/assets/javascripts.

I then try to require them from my application.js but I get a sprockets::filenotfound error.

Application.js :

```
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require counterup
//= require waypoints
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require turbolinks
```

Am I correctly placing them in vendor/assets? 
How do I correctly 'require' them?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all check whether any kind of gems already exists for such library. If it's not I usually finish with placing it into `app/assets/javascripts` and including it in `application.js` as an average script.

Maybe it would be slightly better to create a special folder like `app/assets/javascripts/src` or something like this to keep all third-party libraries

Comment: yeah just putting it in app/assets/javascripts works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Third party libraries should be added to vendor/javascript and not to app/assets/javascripts

Then in app/javascript/application.js you add the line

`//= require FILENAME`

Real example of getting howler.js. Get the howler.js file and put it in vendor/javascript

[image: howler js vendor]

Then add the line `//= require howler` to app/javascript/application.js

[image: add require howler]

Here is a video explaining this [video explanation adding third party js libraries](https://gorails.com/episodes/including-third-party-javascript-libraries-with-rails)